# Misclassified audit question?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I received "This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass," after voting to close https://askubuntu.com/review/close/261614 .

On one of the proposed answers, the OP comments:
"...I enter  and  but it says incorrect login. Now I have installed 13.04 back...."  Prakash Gautam May 5 at 12:02

Since the OP moved away from his problematic 14.04 installation and the problem is no longer solvable, I was going to specify closing as off-topic with, "This describes problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers."

I have seen this used frequently for exactly this case (OP re-installs systems to resolve the problem), and I've used it myself before.

Isn't this a clear case where the question should be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downvote (nobody receives the same audit), vote to close (rightfully), and move on.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that the audit questions aren't used for other people.  In that case, they still need to tweak their algorithm, but I can't expect it to be perfect. (For this one, the extended discussion in the comments was a red flag in my opinion.)

Comment: They need to tweak that. I have also had some weird audits. At the end the one that did not pass was the audit system lol.